# How do I install SQLAlchemy with cmd in Windows

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pip

I'm using Python 3.82, pip 20.0.2 and I'm getting the following error when I try to install SQLAlchemy through cmd. I have tried through PyCharm and its giving an "Exception Error" again.

```
C:\Users\Takunda Mafuta>pip install SQLAlchemy 
Collecting SQLAlchemy
  Downloading SQLAlchemy-1.3.15.tar.gz (6.1 MB)
     |█████▌                          | 1.0 MB 4.6 kB/s eta 0:18:11ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\takunda mafuta\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 425, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "c:\users\takunda mafuta\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 507, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "c:\users\takunda mafuta\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "c:\users\takunda mafuta\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 454, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "c:\users\takunda mafuta\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\http\client.py", line 498, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "c:\users\takunda mafuta\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "c:\users\takunda mafuta\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "c:\users\takunda mafuta\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this exception occurs when **your network is unstable** or **your connection to the PyPi repository** is unstable. Try to set a repository URL that is close to your location (e.g. in your country). Found a URL (by searching "pypi url" + "#your_country") and set it follows this [link](https://wiki.onap.org/display/DW/Configure+and+customize+pip)